# CSP img-src policy blocks svg despite data: being allowed on Chrome

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, security, svg, content-security-policy

On my Heroku deployed website, I get the following error for loading an img tag with svg data:

Refused to load the image 'data:image/png;base64,...' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self'".

However, when checking the index page headers, the CSP policy is:

```
Content-Security-Policy:child-src 'self'; connect-src *; default-src 'self'; 
img-src 'self' data: chrome-extension-resource:; font-src 'self' data: 
fonts.googleapis.com/css fonts.gstatic.com; object-src 'self'; media-src 
'self' data:; manifest-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'nonce-...' 'unsafe-
inline' cdn.polyfill.io www.google-analytics.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-
inline' blob: fonts.googleapis.com/css; base-uri 'none'
```

I load the image using img tag:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';

function Logo() {
  return <object data={logo} aria-label="logo" type="image/svg+xml" 
style={{ height: '8em', paddingTop: '1em' }} />;
}
```

Why does the error quote "img-src 'self'" when the server header clearly shows "img-src 'self' data: chrome-extension-resource:"?

Comment: Does the document have a `meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" ` element with a different policy?

Comment: That was not the problem. I redid the whole policy and it seems to work.

Comment: @Heiki, I'm having the same problem. Could you clarify what you meant by "redid the whole policy"?